# admin.messaging().sendToTopic exceeds daily CPU allocation limit

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have the following Firebase Functions code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const payLoad = {
        data: {
            execute_noise_measure: "true"
        }
    };

    const options = {
        priority: "high"
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("all", payLoad, options).then(function(response) {
            return console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            return console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });
});
```

The function executes properly giving "Successfully sent message:" response in the console. Unfortunately each function call consumes significant amount of "CPU allocation in function invocations". After just few calls, my daily limit is exceeded giving: "Error: quota exceeded (Quota exceeded for quota group 'CPUMilliSecondsDailyNonbillable" 
[image]

[image]

[image]
What could be the reason for that? How can I improve my code?

Comment: I don't think `sendToTopic` is supposed to take a lot of local CPU time, as the actual fan-out from the topic to device IDs happens on Google's servers. Can you time/find how long each individual call takes?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just added screen shot with the logs output. Check my edit. It seems that the function finishes with the timeout. How can I avoid that?

Comment: That sounds like the promise you return never resolves, which would definitely explain why you're eating up your free CPU quota in a few calls. That `return console.log(...)` looks suspicious to me, since `console.log()` returns `undefined`. I'd separate out the `console.log(...); return true;`.

Comment: It seemed to be part of the problem. I separated those statements according your suggestion but it wasn't enough. I needed to add `response.status(200).send("ok");` as well. Now everything is working fine and and CPU allocation usage dropped somewhere like 400 times.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that your function is HTTP triggered. In that case you indeed need to send a response to the client to terminate the function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Frank van Puffelen [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54051813/admin-messaging-sendtotopic-exceeds-daily-cpu-allocation-limit#comment94940967_54051813) I was able to get finally the OK 200. It seems that my code was missing the response status send. This is the code which works:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const payload = {
        data: {
            execute_noise_measure: "true"
        }
    };

    const options = {
        priority: "high"
    };

    admin.messaging().sendToTopic("all", payload).then(() => {
        response.status(200).send("ok");

        return true;
    }).catch((err) => {
        response.status(500).send(err);

        return true;
    });
});
```